# DXF to ArcGIS Pro - scattering of lines

Tags: arcgis-pro, dxf, cad, dwg, sdna

I am trying to import 3D CAD polylines (DXF file) into ArcGIS Pro. However some lines scatter randomly when importing, and I am unable to understand why, or how to prevent it.

[image]

In this image, the red lines that are seemingly floating should not be there, they should be a part of the network of lines on the bottom left.

What I have tried:

1. I made sure all the CAD polylines are of the same type (open curves, and removed closed curves)
2. I checked if all the lines intersect correctly, using _Intersect in Rhino, and they do.

The problem persists after Georeferencing in ArcGIS Pro and significantly disrupts analysis. Has anyone faced this and solved it?

Comment: If you’re importing your DXF into a file geodatabase, have you checked to see whether that feature class is Z-enabled?

Comment: I've never had much luck importing DXF into ArcMap. If you can get your hands on Autocad Map3d, you can get it to import/export 3d shapefiles, which has worked for me in the past.

Comment: Are the X and Y coordinates OK?  Ie, is it just the Z coordinate - elevation - that's incorrect?.  (The correctness (or otherwise) of the X and Y coordinates would be easier to visualise on a plain map, than on a 3D scene.)

Comment: Thanks all, not sure exactly what the problem was (the file was z-enabled, and multiple lines -not just z coordinates- were scattered), but importing the Rhino dwg file into AutoCAD Map3D and _mapexport worked! Got a clean shapefile in ArcGIS.